# Unable to call initializer for subclass of generic type

Tags: swift, generics

UPDATE: Question and title have been restated based on changes that were made in response to the initial question.

---

I've got a base class that implements a generic class method for creating new instances. The simplified logic of this class method is as follows

```
class MyBaseClass {

    required init(_ record:MyRecordType) {
        println("Entered MyBaseClass.init")
        // Initialize base class from record
    }

    class func retrieveInstance<T:MyBaseClass>(name:String, callback:(T) -> ()) {
        let myRecord:MyRecordType = ... // Perform fetch to get a record for name
        let result = (T.self as T.Type)(myRecord) // Code currently crashes with BAD_ACCESS at this line
        callback(result)
    }
}
```

I then implement a subclass of this base class with logic like the following

```
class MySubClass : MyBaseClass {

    required init(_ record:MyRecordType) {
        println("Entered MySubClass.init")
        // Initialize subclass from record
        super.init(record)
    }
}
```

Next, I try to invoke the generic class method

```
class AnotherClass {
    func successCallback(result:MySubclass) {
        // Handle callback
    }
    MySubClass.retrieveInstance("objectName", callback:successCallback)
}
```

When creating an instance of the class - the line marked with a comment identifying the crash location - I am expecting the init method from `MySubClass` to be invoked. (This odd notation is based on the bug workaround suggested in the replies)

Instead of calling the `init` method for `MySubClass`, this code crashes with a BAD_ACCESS. I have been unable to find any nil references or anything else that would explain this crash.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the BAD_ACCESS. I assume you are using some asynchronous call, maybe the problem is around there.

Comment: @rintaro - I have finally been able to isolate the problem. It turns out to be unrelated to asynchrony and instead relates to mixing an overridden initializer with a required initializer (I'll post a full description below). Since it was your answer that at least got me pointed in the right direction I'd like to give you the right answer credit here, but you seem to have deleted your answer. Feel free to repost if you'd like me to give you credit for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a lot of help from the answer originally posted by @rintaro, I was able to solve this problem, although there is still an oddity that I will post under a separate question.

As it turns out, @rintaro was absolutely correct in the need to initialize the instance of the generic type using the following syntax:

```
let result = (T.self as T.Type)(myRecord)
```

This works as long as the base class `MyBaseClass` declares this initializer with a `required` tag:

```
public class MyBaseClass {
    public required init(_ record:MyRecordType) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and the subclass `MySubClass` implements the matching initializer:

```
public class MySubClass : MyBaseClass {
    public required init (_ record:MyRecordType) {
        ...
        super.init(record)
    }
}
```

Where things fail, however is when I actually have a 3-level class hierarchy and the initializer hierarchy throughs an `override` into the mix. To envision this, consider a set of class that represents nodes in a tree structure:

```
public class Node {
    public init(_ record:MyRecordType) {
       ...
    }
}

public class RootNode : Node {
    override public init(_ record:MyRecordType) {
        ...
        super.init(record)
    }
    public class func <T:RootNode>retrieveAll(success:(T) -> ()) {
        // Retrieve all instances of root node subclass T, and invoke success callback with new T instance
    }
}

public class ChildNode : Node {
    public init(_ record:MyRecordType, parentNode:Node) {
        ...
        super.init(record)
    }
    public class func <T:ChildNode>retrieveChildren(parent:Node, success:(T) -> ()) {
        // Retrieve all child T instances of parent node, and invoke success callback with new T instance
    {
}
```

The problem occurs in the implementation of the `RootNode` class's `retrieveAll` method. In order for it to work as described by @rintaro, I need the `init` in `RootNode` to be marked with the `required` keyword. But because it also overrides the initializer from `Node`, it also needs to have the `override` keyword. So I try to use both keywords in the declaration:

```
override required public init(_ record:MyRecordType) {
    ...
}
```

The Swift compiler accepts this, but when I use it to initialize an instance from within the `retrieveAll` method, it crashes with a BAD_ACCESS.

I was able to work around this problem by changing the method signature of the `NodeClass` just slightly so that its `RootNode` subclass doesn't need to override:

```
public class Node {
    public init(record:MyRecordType) {
        ...
    }
}
public class RootNode {
    public required init(_ record:MyRecordType) {
        ...
        super.init(record:record)
    }
}
```

By doing this workaround, my subclasses of `RootNode` can properly implement the required initializer, and the `retrieveAll` method in `RootNode` can properly instantiate instances of those subclasses.

Comment: Once you add the required initializer on the base class and subclasses, you can just use `T()`.

Comment: @seanwoodward - Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be true. When I call the initializer using T(myRecord) it fails, when I call it the way rintaro suggested it works. The failure with T(myRecord) seems to happen because of a BAD_ACCESS exception when getting the "record" property of the instance, which should have been set to the value of "myRecord" that was passed in.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. The call to the generic initializer `T()` worked for me in simple tests. I'm hopeful the issues can be addressed in future versions of the compiler.

Comment: As far as I can tell the init function must have the "required" specifier or it won't work.